# How to correctly determine if key exists in multidimensional javascript object using a recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to create a recursive function that will loop through a multidimensional object and test whether the key exists in a separate object. If the key does not exist I want to break the loop and return false, if all the keys exist I want to return true.

The problem I am having is that the function always seems to be returning true. Here is the code I am using:

```
var properties = {'global': {'structure' : {'body': {}}}};

var testExists = {'global': {'structure': {'test': 'value'}}};

if( ! this.exists(properties, testExists)) {
   console.log("DOESNT EXIST");
}


exists: function(destination, source) {
    var exists = true;

    check:
    for (var property in source) {

        if(destination[property]) {
            arguments.callee(destination[property], source[property]);
        }
        else
        {
            exists = false;
            break check;
        }
    }

    console.log(exists);

    return exists;
},
```

When I view the console to see the value of 'exists' I see two line the first false the second is true, so there must be an error with the recursion I am creating

Comment: When executing your code, I see `false`, `true`, `true` - what did you expect?

Comment: I want to break the loop/function as soon as there is a false and return false. So on getting to the key 'test' in the testExists object  as it doesn't exist in the properties object I want the function to return false

Comment: Your function *does* return `false` for that object - yet that returned value doesn't stop the calling function from returning `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you don't use the result of the recursively called function.

Also, you shouldn't use `arguments.callee`, but a function name, and potentially check for the parameters to be objects before enumerating their properties. And you might want to check also for properties of `destination` that are not in the enumerated `source`.

Try this:

```
function equal(destination, source) {
    if (Object(destination)!==destination || Object(source)!==source)
        // at least one of them is a primitive value
        return destination == source; // maybe use strict equality === ?
    for (var prop in source)
        if (!(prop in destination) || !equal(source[prop], destination[prop]))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Note that you can name a function and still assign it to an object property or variable. If you do both, the function's name will only be visible inside the function, which means you can still call it recursively without polluting the namespace. It's the best of both worlds.

Comment: There's no need for that awkward check if either parameter is a "real object," for..in will happily operate on a number or a string. hasOwnProperty, on the other hand, is important.

Comment: @Kiyura: `for in` will happily loop through any enumerable properties on `Number`/`String` `.prototype`.

Comment: It will loop through any enumerable properties on normal objects too. As I showed in my answer, it's important to include a hasOwnProperty check, or just replace the falsy check with that entirely.

Comment: That's not necessarily what is wanted, and also does not really match the cases. Just check out what your function does when called with `exists({proof:"someString"}, {proof:{toString:{oops:true}}})`

Comment: At least it doesn't give "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value" :P Anyway, that situation is kind of unavoidable without awkwardly complicating the function (like you have). It's best to just avoid using symbols that have already been taken in the global object or in basic prototypes like that.

Comment: Um, that was a bit awkward when comparing `"someString"=={toString:{}}`, however, then check `exists({proof:"someString"}, {proof:{charAt:{call:true}}})`

Comment: Maybe it gives the expected result, but it compares `String.prototype.charAt` with `{call:true}`…

Answer (score 1):

You're making it more complicated than it needs to be:

```
function exists(destination, source) {
    for (var property in source) {
        if(destination.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if (!exists(destination[property], source[property])) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}​
```

Note that .hasOwnProperty means that this will only compare direct properties of the objects and not those inherited from prototypes. I assumed that this was what you were looking for.

Also note: it actually uses the result of the recursive calls, it recurses properly, it uses .hasOwnProperty instead of just checking falsiness, and it doesn't use intermediate variables to store the result (which wouldn't work in a recursion the way you were using them, anyway).

One more thing: This will only go "one way," i.e. any properties in the destination that are not in the source will not be checked. To check both ways, you have to call it twice or extend it to loop over both.

Comment: Your function doesn't check all properties of an object, you should either mention that or fix it.

Comment: That was not my argument - your function can't handle objects that have more than one property.

Comment: This function either always returns false or I get a 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' error

Comment: Sounds like you're calling this on a huge object. Recursive functions will always pose a risk of exceeding the call stack size. You need to reimplement this iteratively if you want it to work on objects of arbitrary size. Can you demonstrate with a smaller example (in a jsfiddle) how it's returning false when you don't expect it to? And do you understand what the function is doing?

Comment: This generates an 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' error for me - http://jsfiddle.net/9g72p/1/

Comment: Sorry, no, aside from reimplementing it iteratively. That would be a good exercise, too. ;) (You could ask a new question if you have run into trouble doing that, but be specific.)